# Terminology question in model category theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology, model-categories

This is a terminology question. That will help me to write down my papers. In Marc Olschok's PhD available [here](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~gaucher/marc_these.pdf) (I cannot find it anymore on the Internet so it is in my webpage, the original URL is welcome), Cisinski's constructions are generalized to any locally presentable category equipped with a cartesian cylinder with respect to a cofibrant small weak factorization system (Theorem 2.2.5 page 25). I need a name for this structure because I have a lot of model categories constructed like that in my work. Here are the ideas:

1. A *cartesian model category*: the terminology of cartesian model category is already used [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+closed+model+category).
2. A *Cisinski-Olschok model category*: it is very long but it is my favorite choice.
3. A *cylindric model category*: since there are cylinders in any model category, this terminology does not seem to be a good idea.

And I call the set of cofibrations $S$ in the statement of Theorem 2.2.5 the set of *generating anodyne cofibrations*. Any suggestion before I make a decision ?

Comment: Marc Olschok's webpage can be found at http://is.muni.cz/www/183259/index.html and his profile at http://math.stackexchange.com/users/19950/marc-olschok (last seen on December 26th).